# Using sed to find and replace text in smb.conf file

Tags: sed

Hey guys I am new to the website. I am writing a bash script that installs and configures Samba. I am using a prompt to ask the user to enter the ip address and then I want to use the input and put it into the "hosts allow =" in the smb.conf file. I have tried using this command:

```
sed -i "/${line}/ s/^${line} */${get_ip}/" /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

but it removes the hosts allow = in the file. If anyone could help me with this I would deeply appreciate it.

My variables used within the sed command are

```
line="hosts allow ="
get_ip=`hostname -I`
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the `&` (what was matched) "operator" in the sed replacment string, i.e.

```
sed -i "/${line}/ s/^${line} */&${get_ip}/" /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

IHTH

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your script in several ways:

1. `hostname -I` seems to be distro-dependent, e.g. the same version 1.100 (2001-04-14) has `-I` option in CentOS 6.5, but not in Gentoo. Maybe you can use try/catch block to check if it works.
2. According to [the specification](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html), in most of the cases white space is ignored, so with `^${line}` you might miss the parameter if is not at the beginning of the line.
3. In `/${line}/ s/${line} */${get_ip}/` which is essentially `/p/ s/p/r/`, you don't need to specify the address range (`/p/`) because it is the same as the search pattern, so it's equivalent to just `s/p/r/`.
4. If you need to replace the whole value for this parameter, you can use the following:

   ```
   sed -i "s/\(${line}\).*/\1 ${get_ip}/" /etc/samba/smb.conf
   ```

   This means: search for a group that consists of `${line}` + any characters until the end of line and replace it with the content of the group + space + `${get_ip}`.
5. if you need to append the value to the existing value, you can use the following:

   ```
   sed -i "s/${line}.*/& ${get_ip}/" /etc/samba/smb.conf
   ```

   This means: search for `${line}` + any characters until the end of line and replace it with everything that matched + space + `${get_ip}`. Actually, this will work only if the value is just a part of the same line, not a multiline string with `\` continuation symbols (for details see [here](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html)). To take into account this case use the following:

   ```
   sed -i "s/\(${line}[^\]*\)\([\]\?\)/\1 ${get_ip} \2/" /etc/samba/smb.conf
   ```

   This means: search for two groups that consist of `${line}` + any characters except for `\` (the first group) and zero or one occurrence of `\` character (the second group) and replace it with the content of the first group + space + `${get_ip}` + space + the content of the second group.